# Getting : " STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" when attempting to compile this C++ code

Tags: c++

What could be the problem? I thought it might have been with initializing the pointer when I used strtok, but that did not fix the problem. Sorry if this is dumb, I am very new to this.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std ;

int main() {

//initialize and get input into a string, turn into a cstring
    string intstring ;  
    cout << "Enter five integers: " ;
    cin >> intstring ;
    char * cstr = new char [intstring.length()+1];
    strcpy (cstr, intstring.c_str());

//use strtok to convert into an array of strings
    int intarray[5] ;
    char * point = strtok ( cstr , " " ) ;;
    int i = 0 ;
    while ( point != NULL ) {
        intarray[i] = atoi ( point ) ;
        point = strtok ( cstr , " " ) ;
        i++ ;
        }

//get the sum of all integers
int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 , i++ ;) {
        sum += intarray[i] ;    
    }   

//sort the array of integers
sort(intarray, (intarray + 5)) ;

//print the mean and median
    cout <<  "Median is " << intarray[2] << endl;
    cout << "Geometric mean is " ;
    cout << (sum / 5) << setprecision(4);

    return (0) ;
    }
```

Comment: The `point = strtok ( cstr , " " )` inside the loop should be `point = strtok ( NULL , " " )`. You're repeatedly getting the first value in `cstr`, which means the unchecked `i`-loop eventually overruns its array.

Comment: Do you get the error really if compiling or when running your program? If really during compilation: why don't you share which compiler you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The two errors are:

- `cin >> intstring` only reads the first number, stopping when it finds a space. You want `getline(cin, intstring)` to read the whole line
- Only the first call to `strtok` should pass `cstr` as the argument. Subsequent calls should pass `NULL` to continue where the last call ended. You keep reading the first value until `i` goes out of bounds and causes a crash (or other undefined behaviour).

But, since this is C++ not C, there's really no need for `strtok`. The simple way to read five numbers from the input is

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cin >> intarray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can compile the code without any warnings or errors (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Prof.). However, you have some bugs in the code:

```
string intstring ;  
cout << "Enter five integers: " ;
cin >> intstring ;
```

You pull out *one* number from cin into the string, the rest is ignored. Either use another separator, for example ',', and do your split operation with this one or take another approach:

```
int intarray[5] ;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cin >> intarray[i];
}
```

Furthermore, *strtok* is used another way (subsequent calls have to use NULL as first argument):

```
char * point = strtok ( cstr , " " );
int i = 0 ;
while ( point != NULL ) {
    intarray[i] = atoi ( point );
    point = strtok ( NULL , "," ); // Pass NULL as first argument
    i++;
}
```

Also make sure you don't run into a buffer overflow, if the loop continues and tries to access, e.g., the 6th element of *intarray*

Answer (score 0):

Your error "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" is not error about the code. If code is not correct then you would get 'syntax error' or 'unknown keyword' and such. This is an exception error of compiler itself.

I am getting the same error when I'm compiling my x64 project with 2010 command line compiler (with mingw processing make files). After I switched to 2015 there I had no such errors.